# Kubernetes ingress nginx controller routing using HTTP headers

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have installed Kubernetes ingress nginx controller as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md). I am looking further to customize the routing logic by parsing HTTP header and altering the base ingress route accordingly. I know that it can be done using Lua script to be executed as part of the server routing configuration.
Can anyone advise how I inject the lua script into Kubernetes ingress nginx controller configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a quite similar task. Previously we have a separate Nginx instance which has openresty installed.

My solution is to build our own customized image based on kubernetes nginx-ingress, and also include the openresty module inside the module.

Comment: the nginx image that we use already has Lua inside. I see it by looking into container and seeing massive Lua scripts as part of the nginx config file. Can you provide more details about what you mean under customization and how you incorporate the customization?
We are OK with having a hardcoded rules for the beginning. But we need to be able to change them dynamically latter, to support large set of routing paths.